# В чем отличие между HTTP методами HEAD и OPTIONS?

Tags: веб-программирование, сеть, http, веб-сервер

В чем отличие между HTTP методами HEAD и OPTIONS? я знаю лишь что в ответ на OPTIONS сервер должен отдать Allow со списком поддерживаемых методов. Есть ли еще какие либо концептуальные/технические отличия?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У этих запросов разное назначение:

- **HEAD** - служит для проверки существования ресурса, он полностью аналогичен **GET**, но без возврата **тела** ответа
- **OPTIONS** - служит для получения параметров для ресурса или для сервера в целом и при этом сам ресурс ни как не затрагивается (то есть это более дешевая операция по сравнению с **HEAD**)

**OPTIONS** возвращает параметры в заголовке. Список параметров зависит о ресурса и/или сервера. Обычно это заголовок **Allow**, который описывает какие методы доступны для ресурса.

Comment: а что понимается под параметрами которые получает options? и как они возвращаются, в виде заголовков или ка кто иначе?

Comment: @Artur дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 3):

**`HEAD`**

Данный метод по своей сути похож на GET, но сервер отвечает на запрос одним лишь заголовком. (Отсюда и название метода.) Применяется, например, чтобы узнать, существует ли в сети тот или иной URL и не произошло ли каких-нибудь изменений.

---

**`OPTIONS`**

Метод представляет запрос информации об опциях соединения, доступных в цепочке запросов/ответов, идентифицируемой запрашиваемым URI (Request-URI). Этот метод позволяет клиенту определять опции и/или требования, связанные с ресурсом, или возможностями сервера, но не производя никаких действий над ресурсом и не инициируя его загрузку.

Comment: То есть при HEAD сам запрос выполняется, но не возвращается? А в OPTIONS даже не доходит до выполнения, обрывая после отправки заголовков?

Answer (score 2):

Отличие этих методов - в том, что HEAD запрашивает информацию о ресурсе, а OPTIONS запрашивает информацию о методах доступа к ресурсу.

Более подробно.

Заголовки, возвращаемые методом HEAD, обязаны соответствовать заголовкам, возвращаемым методом GET. При этом, метод HEAD не имеет никакого отношения к методам POST, PUT, DELETE и прочим.

В то же время, настройки доступа, возвращаемые методом OPTIONS, имеют отношение сразу ко всем методом ресурса - GET, POST, PUT, DELETE и пр.

---

Если говорить о применении, то метод HEAD может использоваться чтобы получить информацию о странице без скачивания самой страницы. Метод OPTIONS же используется, в основном, механизмом Preflight request в CORS или для обнаружения поддерживаемых сервером фич в WebDAV.